# Android studio wont update my app on build

Tags: java, android

So when i add an new theme or add code etc it does not update the app, like if i add a button, and click run it will run and open a older version on the app. i have tried to rebuild, i have tried to re install, like a totally clean uninstall and reinstall on the app, make sure the run instance is ok and practically everything, even the edit config. I reinstalled android studio but still have the same issue.

Activity main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="dogboy602k.com.myapplication.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login to your account"
    android:id="@+id/textViewHello"
    android:textColor="#100606"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/emailField" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailField"
    android:text="Email"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/passwordField"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#dedddd"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:onClick="clickFunction"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dogboy602k.com.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[instant run settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SZXx.png)

[edit config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbins.png)

Comment: You have instant run disabled, if that is what you are asking about

Comment: @cricket_007 I enabled everything in the run instance and still won't update

Comment: Emulator or physical device? When you clean and rebuild, can you check the date attribute of the apk file in the build folder?

Comment: @cricket_007 physical devices, and im confused on the second part

Comment: Like when you edit any file, you can right-click and inspect the properties to see the modification date. If this does not update, then that mean you are installing a previous version of the app

Comment: @cricket_007 where do i find the APK file?

Comment: In the build folder, I believe

Comment: @cricket_007 i do no see a apk file " C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\build"

Answer (score 0):

Click here, refresh all your projects:

[image]